# Get Custom Post's Post Id By URL doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

Please Note: The below problem is completely related to custom post type.

In my new WordPress project I am trying to show the thumbnail and title of the previous post, I tried multiple ways but couldn't succeed.

I think it will be only possible when I get the id of previous post, I tried:

```
<?php $postid = url_to_postid( $url ); ?>
```

But as Wordpress codex says this function does not return the post id for custom post types.

So please tell me anyway to do this.

Comment: get_adjacent_post doesn't works for you? it fetches the previous post according to current post type, so it should solve your problem

Comment: get_adjacent_post works when I just use it to get permalink of previous post but I also want to get value of a custom field of that previous post along with the permalink.

Comment: it returns post object, you can probably get the post id and use the same to fetch the meta values for post, or you have a problem in that?

Answer (score -1):

You probably have to build your own query, so then you can use the following code:

```
/* A custom Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
// looping through the query2 result, you may use some other code
while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->next_post();//here your next post is set
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); //do not forget this line!
```

This example code is taken from http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query where you can find other examples and custom queries. Read especially this part of the page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters, I think, it solves your problem.